# Table of Contents or TOC lines without page numbers

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, page-numbering

Is it possible to create a TOC (table of contents) with `\section`s and `\subsection`s,  but without the page numbers on the right hand side? 
I know this defeats the purpose of a TOC but for knowledge's sake I want to know if LaTeX gives this flexibility.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

LaTeX is flexible, especially if you are able to read sources to redefine macros.

1. You could redefine `\addcontentsline`:

   `\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[3]{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}}}`
2. Alternatively, you could redefine `\contentsline`, like Herbert did, or this way:

   `\renewcommand*{\contentsline}[3]{\csname l@#1\endcsname{#2}{}}`
3. If you wish to remove page numbers for a certain level, such as subsection, redefine `\l@subsection{title}{page number}`. Perhaps you would like to do that, because dotted toc lines, used for certain levels, are not meaningful without the page number.
4. You could even redefine `\thepage` locally to be empty, in a group together with `\tableofcontents`.

Note: If you use the `hyperref` package, solutions should be modified since that package makes modifications to TOC macros for hyperlinking.

For example, the first solution would need an extra parameter for the hyperlink label. This fourth parameter can be left empty if you do not wish to have a hyperlink for that TOC entry.

`\renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[4]{\addtocontents{#1}{\protect\contentsline{#2}{#3}{}{#4}}}`

Comment: @Stefan-Yes I am using Hyperref package. How to modify the solution.

Comment: @Aku: hyperref uses one further argument for the link name. I'll check that in the evening (UTC) when I will have access to LaTeX.

Comment: Could you please check the solutions for hyperref? Also, how can I put something (one time only) that is formatted like a chapter* in the toc, but without the page number?

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: Thanks for providing this great answer! Would you be able to indicate how to modify these solutions for documents that are using hyperref? I also have the same question as the above comment, namely, how can I (for instance) have some sections appear with page numbers, and others without?

Comment: The last command (provided for `hyperref`) does not work. The error is `! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 54.
<inserted text> 
 \fi `

Answer (score 19):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\let\Contentsline\contentsline
\renewcommand\contentsline[3]{\Contentsline{#1}{#2}{}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{foo}
\section{bar}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to work correctly with `hyperref`.

Comment: @Richard: but it must beloaded before the redefinition of `\contensline`

Comment: Seems to work correctly without `hyperref`