# Add text to TOC without dotted-lines and line number

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, formatting

Despite following many suggestions on the net, I have the following issue. I am using TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX. [I have posted the same on Latex Community Forum]. I have not used/tried the `tocloft` package yet. I am currently using the `thesis2` class.

Objective: In my table of contents, I want a text "Chapter" without the dotted lines and the page number. Eg.,

```
============================================

Table of Contents

Acknowledgments ................ ii

Abstract ........................ v

Chapter

1 Introduction .................. 1

1.1 Network Design .............. 1

1.1.1 Steiner Tree Problems ..... 2

============================================
```

Trial-1: When I do `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect Chapter}`, it adds the required text (Chapter) to toc. But, the dotted lines and page number is present.

Trial-2: The same happens when I do `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect \numberline{}Chapter}`.

Q1) Also, I want only one-line spacing between "Chapter" and "1 Introduction". Currently, I get 2 line-spacing (like between Acknowledgments and Abstract). How do I get rid of that 2 line spacing and make it 1-line spacing?

Comment: Did you have a look at this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9289/toc-without-page-numbers?

Answer (score 15):

Use `\addtocontents` instead of `\addcontentsline`, and add positive and negative vertical space as appropriate. (Note: I used the `thesis2` class file available [here](http://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/04/46/81/TEX/Archive/thesis2.cls).)

```
\documentclass{thesis2}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\frontmatter

\chapter{Acknowledgments}

\chapter{Abstract}

\mainmatter

\addtocontents{toc}{%
 \protect\vspace{1em}% 
 \protect\noindent Chapter\protect\par
 \protect\vspace{-1em}%
}

\chapter{Introduction}

\section{Network design}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Lockstep - Many thanks for this neat solution. Really appreciate.

Comment: @srinivas: Please consider marking my answer as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below its vote count.

Comment: @lockstep Do you know how to do the reversed case? I want the dotted line after acknowledgements, abstract etc, but by default of tocloft they don't have the dotted leaders. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution based on the suggestions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9289/5640). It's 'cleaner' in the sense that you don't set spacing and indentation explicitly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\notocnumsection}[1]{
  \bgroup%
  \renewcommand*{\addcontentsline}[3]{\addtocontents{##1}{\protect\contentsline{##2}{##3}{}}}%
  \section{#1}%
  \egroup
}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{foo}
This is the foo section.
\notocnumsection{bar}
This is the bar section.
\section{baz}
This is the baz section.
\end{document}
```

It does not, however, address your wish regarding spacing. But I believe you should think about changing the spacing once for all chapter-level toc entries. For that, I think the `tocloft` package should be useful (documentation [here](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf)).