# How to unset the pagenumbering in the toc?

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

How to set the right footer of the ToC to empty?

I've tried this way, but it hasn't resolve the issue :

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    {\raggedleft \reset@font
    \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
    \par\nobreak}%
  \par\nobreak
  \vspace*{30\p@}
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
  {\raggedright \Huge #1}%
  \par\nobreak
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 45\p@
}}
\makeatother

\rfoot{\thepage}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}\tableofcontents{}
\thispagestyle{empty}\listoffigures
\thispagestyle{empty}\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: At least one problem with the current setup is that you're using `@` in document commands *without* setting the appropriate catcodes. See [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](http://goo.gl/HYwLd)

Comment: `\pagenumbering{gobble}\tableofcontents \listoffigures ... \pagenumbering{arabic} ...` would help? I'm not 100% sure what exactly you're after.

Comment: @Werner, I've updated my post.

Comment: @tohecz, that have only deleted the first page of toc's pagenumbering and haven't unset the right foot pagenumber of the others.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table of Contents or TOC lines without page numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9289/table-of-contents-or-toc-lines-without-page-numbers)

Comment: @musicman, the OP want to remove the page number from the table of contents page, not the page numbers shown on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you need to `\pagestyle{empty}` for the ToCs, and as well to suppress the effect of `\thispagestyle` of the command `\chapter*` called by them:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\makeatletter
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@
    {\raggedleft \reset@font
    \scshape \vphantom{\@chapapp{} \thechapter}
    \par\nobreak}%
  \par\nobreak
  \vspace*{30\p@}
  \interlinepenalty\@M
  \usefont{OT1}{ptm}{b}{n}
  {\raggedright \Huge #1}%
  \par\nobreak
  \par\nobreak
  \vskip 45\p@
}}
\makeatother
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begingroup % make the following \let local
\makeatletter
\let\thispagestyle\@gobble % suppress \thispagestyle
\makeatother
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\endgroup
\clearpage % to make the following \pagestyle effective at the right page
\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter{First chapter}
Dummy text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you load the [tocloft](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft) package, you could issue the command

```
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}
```

to suppress the display of page numbers in the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables.

You can load the `tocloft` package with the option `titles` to leave the form of the headers of the ToC, the LoF, and the LoT unaffected:

```
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\tocloftpagestyle{empty}
```

Comment: sorry but that will change my toc's customized style and it hasn't solved my issue.

Comment: I'm sorry (I was talking about the font style and size.)

Comment: @dgs Load the package like this: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Thanks. I've added this information in the body of my answer.

Comment: I'm quite unhappy about this answer not getting accepted.

Comment: @tohecz - Thanks. The OP may have been anxious to accept the first answer that more or less met all objectives. In my initial answer I just mentioned the `\tocloftpagestyle{empty}` as the page numbering issue seemed to be the main concern. It wasn't until after the OP mentioned in a follow-up comment the need to preserve his/her customizations of the `\@makeschapterhead` macro that I added the part about using the option `titles` when loading `tocloft`.