# How do i remove the chapter number from a section?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to show my "Attachments" in ToC, but I don't want there to be a chapter number in front of it. How do I remove it? Its the "Vedlegg" part in the picture.

Thanks for any help.[image]

Comment: Did you try `\chapter*`?

Comment: You have to clarify your question: 1. Do you want to remove the chapter number both in the chapter heading and in the table of contents? 2. Do you want to keep the chapter number in the chapter heading and only remove it in the table of content?

Answer (score 1):

It is already answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9289/table-of-contents-or-toc-lines-without-page-numbers).

> If you wish to remove page numbers for a certain level, such as subsection, redefine \l@subsection{title}{page number}.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! :) I'm actually not too sure the OP was asking about the page numbers, I think they actually wanted to remove the section number, i.e. the **14** part of **14 Vedlegg**

Comment: Hi. Thanks! oh, so in that case [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110840/how-to-remove-chapter-numbering-without-removing-it-from-tableofcontents) is the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to use the starred form: `\chapter*{Attachments}` associated with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Attachments}`. This last bit is needed because the starred form strips down the chapter number but also prevents it to appear in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{This is chapter1}
 blah blah
\chapter*{Attachments}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Attachments}
 blah blah
\end{document}
```

will give:

[image: tableOfContents]